# git merge wont save latest changes

Tags: git, gerrit

I am using gerrit. I made some changes and uploaded this patch set(patch5).

commit history

a--b--merge commit--c--d--e--f--HEAD

I see merge conflict, so I did a git pull and resolve conflicts and uploaded patchset 6.

a--b--c--d--e--f--merge commit(HEAD)

Now the problem is all the changes I made in patch5 is gone. I have tried rebase, but I could not get the changes in patch5 with merge conflicts gone.

How do I rebase with patch5 and put it on top of the branch?